# Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374) [CLion + SDL2]

Tags: c++, mingw, clion

While I'm trying to close program, I want to delete dynamic SDL_surface array as usual through the for-loop, but program finishes with exit code -1073740940. When I commenting this loop, program closes with 0 exit code. So, what's the problem? Here is code:

```
void close(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Surface* surface, SDL_Surface* keys[]) {
//free memory
for( int i = 0; i < KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL; ++i )
{
    //KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL is defined in enum
    SDL_FreeSurface(keys[i]);
    keys[i] = nullptr;
}

SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
surface = nullptr;

SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
window = nullptr;

SDL_Quit();
```

I'm a beginner, so I'm just trying to learn SDL2 basics.

UPDATE:
Here is enum section code:

```
enum KeyPressSurfaces {
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT,
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP,
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN,
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL };
```

Also here's the using this array in code:

```
bool loadMedia(SDL_Surface* keys[]) {
bool success = true;

keys[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT] = loadSurface("images/press.bmp");
if( keys[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT] == NULL ) {
    std::cout << "Failed to load default image!\n";
    success = false;
} //and so on...
return success; }
```

In main section...

```
SDL_Surface* gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL] = { };
//creating window, surface etc.

if ( !loadMedia(gKeyPressSurfaces) )
        std::cout << "Failed to load media!\n";
    else {
        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event event;
        gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFAULT];

        while ( !quit )
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
            {
                if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) {
                    switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                            case SDLK_UP:
                                gCurrentSurface = gKeyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP];
                                break; // and so on...
```

I did it following LazyFoo's SDL2 tutorials, so I don't understand why this not working.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, exactly it's MinGW

Comment: I believe `0xC0000374` indicates a heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

SDL_FreeSurface(keys[i]); // this line sets keys[i] to nullptr
keys[i] = nullptr;        // you are accessing a nullptr already in this line

comment out keys[i] = nullptr; line then your code will work.

Comment: If `keys[i]` is just a pointer setting it to `nullptr` more than once will not cause any type of issue.

Comment: you mean this is valid? keys[i] = nullptr; then keys[i] = nullptr;? accessing a nullptr then setting it to nullptr is valid?